# how to execute a for loop with delay in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I was just wondering how I can execute a for loop with delays

```
var currentPosition2 = 1;
    for(i=0;i<numberOfSlides;i++) {
        //alert(currentPosition2);
        currentPosition2 = currentPosition2 + 1;
        jQuery('#slideInner').animate({
            'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition2)
        });             
    }
```

at the moment all 3 slides animate at one time, I'd like to make a delay of 3 seconds between each loop and 3 seconds before the loop starts,

any help would be appreciated,

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works for me:

```
var numberOfSlides = 5;
function animateSlides(currentPosition2){
    if(currentPosition2 < numberOfSlides){
        alert(currentPosition2);
        currentPosition2 = currentPosition2 + 1;
        var foo = (function(pos){
            return function(){
                animateSlides(pos);
            };
        })(currentPosition2);
        setTimeout(foo, 3000);
    }
}

animateSlides(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [jQuery's .delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), I think it does what you want. Otherwise setTimeout may be the way to go.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I need to stop the timer when some one is trying to change the slides manually

Comment: yes, setTimeout is what I need but I just dont seem to be able to fit it in the for loop, any help would be appreciated

Comment: @amir what you mean "change the slides manually"? Is there any JS cod running in such a case?

Comment: this is a slide show I didnt provide the rest of the code, cos it's too long, basically when page loads I want the slides to change automatically and if someone clicks on the arrows(left/right) to change the slides manually the timer stops and slides would change

Comment: @amir you want `.delay` anyway. And you can use `.stop` to cancel pending animations if the user input changes.

Comment: From the documentation: The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'd turn the for loop into a recursive function with a delay. I'm not sure exactly what you're doing with currentPosition2 so this may have an off-by-one error.

```
var currentPosition2 = 1;

function animateSlide() {
  // Set manualClickHappened to true if the user clicks a slide
  if (manualClickHappened) {
    return;
  }
  currentPosition2++;
  jQuery('#slideInner').animate({
    'marginLeft': slideWidth * (-currentPosition2)
  });
  if (currentPosition2 < numberOfSlides + 2) // Possible off-by-one
    window.setTimeout(animateSlide, 3 * 1000);
  }
}

window.setTimeout(animateSlide, 3 * 1000);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, currentPosition is the currentPosition of the slide and it increases as the slides animate to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, roughly something like this. Should clean up cleared intervals from the runningIntervals better though.

```
var currentPosition2 = 1;
var runningTimeouts = {};

var secondsBetween;

    for(i=0;i<numberOfSlides;i++) {
        //alert(currentPosition2);
        var j = i;  // use j, if you need i inside the closure (otherwise it wouldn't work)
        var id = setTimeout(function () {
            currentPosition2 = currentPosition2 + 1;
            jQuery('#slideInner').animate({
                'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition2)
            });                   
        }, (i+1)*secondsBetween);   
        runningTimeouts[i] = id;
    }
// then use runningTimeouts to kill timeouts prematurely
// clearTimeout(runningTimeouts[someKey])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your existing code, what you need is:

```
var arrTimers = [];
for(var i = 0; i < numberOfSlides; i++) {
    //alert(currentPosition2);
    currentPosition2++;
    arrTimers.push(window.setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('#slideInner').animate({
            'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition2)
        });
    }, i * 1000));
}
```

This will cause the first animation to occur instantly, the second to occur after 1 second, third after 2 seconds etc.

To stop specific timer use such code:

```
window.clearTimeout(arrTimers[2]);
```

This for example will prevent the third animation from happening.

To clear all timers:

```
$.each(arrTimers, function(index, value) {
   window.clearTimeout(value);
});
```